# Finding $\lambda$ in a constrained variation problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I have the functional 
$$J(y)=\int_0^\infty L(y(x))\,dx +\lambda \left ( \int_0^\infty G(y(x))\,dx-C\right) \tag{1}$$

This gives the constrainted Euler lagrange equation:
$$(L+\lambda G)_y=L_y+\lambda G_y=0 \tag{2}$$

If we can find $L_y$ and $G_y$, then we can solve for $y$ in terms of $\lambda$.

**However, how do we find $\lambda$ itself? What is the general approach for this?**

Answer (score 0):

1. In principle eq. (2) can be solved for $y$ as a function of $x$ and the [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda$.
2. Next plug the solution $y(x;\lambda)$ into the constraint  $$ \int_0^\infty G(y(x))\,dx~=~C$$ to obtain an equation for $\lambda$.